# How do I get TurnBasedMatch information from Google Play Game Service notification

Tags: android, google-play-games

**EDIT:** *this issue has been fixed as of Jan 21, 2014.*

I'm currently developing a Turn-based android game based on the new TurnBasedMatch API in Google Play Game Services.

When an Android device receives a Game invite from another device as a notification, and the user activates the notification, the user is able to decide whether he will accept or decline the invite. If the user chooses to accept the invite, the game is automatic started.

My question is:

If a TurnBasedMatch game is started from the invite notification, how do you retrieve the invited match information in the game? I need this information to initialize the game according to the invite.

I'm using the latest version of the [GameHelper](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/blob/516240d34301fbefa08c3d7874ab75aaf9e7df90/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper.java) class. In this class there is a method called getTurnBasedMatch(). According the the Java-doc i should be able retrieve the match object from the invite here - but for me the result is always null.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer for my own question.
It looks like Google have introduced a bug in the GameHelper.java class.

The bug caused the information regarding the match to be replaced by null when clients other than the GAME client were connecting.

I have fixed the bug and send a pull request to Google:
https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/pull/43